# Flot: Line graph not working correctly when threshold implemented?

Tags: javascript, jquery, flot

I am using flot for a website that I am programming, and I'd like to get a threshold on my data in the line graph but it doesn't seem to be looking. Here is what it ends up looking like:

[image]
https://i.stack.imgur.com/gdhrn.png
I've looked on here for solutions but none of them seemed to work for me. I'm not sure why it is separating the data at this threshold rather than just coloring it differently. I tried removing certain parts of the code but nothing seemed to work. Any suggestions appreciated. Thank you!

EDIT: created jsfiddle of my problem http://jsfiddle.net/catbunny38/cyWrL/
`please help`

Comment: What does your code look like? What does your data look like? Can you create a JSFiddle that reproduces the problem?

Comment: you need to include the code in the question not just a jsfiddle

Comment: Looks like a bug combining the categories and threshold plugin.

Comment: @AbrahamUribe Including part of the code will not reproduce the error and including all of it is too much. The fiddle is enough.

Comment: @Raidri that's what I have come to, but removing the categories plugin still leaves some weird looking data

Comment: @prmech Of course because then the x-values are bunched tightly in a few groups spread over a wide range. (That's probably why he uses categories mode.)

Comment: Without the categories (using ticks instead of the plugin):  http://jsfiddle.net/cyWrL/3/, still some duplicated points.

Answer (score 3):

The problem here is the combination of the categories and threshold plugins. Maybe one of the authors will see this question and fix it.

For now you can fix it by removing the categories plugin and do the categories yourself (see this updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cyWrL/1/)).

Change the data to something like this (easy when you prepare it with serverside code, I changed a few data points manually):

```
var durationList = [
    [1, 48.02335029999415],
    [2, 90.60945035338402],
    [3, 90.89755993498696],
    ...
    [14, 125.0502553939157],
    [15, 7.444523153305053],
    [16, 0.14131634639369117]
];

var tickList = [
    [1, "1315"],
    [2, "1336"],
    [3, "1337"],
    ...
    [14, "5406"],
    [15, "7407"],
    [16, "7410"]
];
```

And for the flot options:

```
xaxis: {
    tickLength: 0,
    ticks: tickList,
    axisLabel: 'FW Release',
    rotateTicks: 90
},
```

Comment: thanks so much, at least theres a way i can get it to have a threshold. hopefully the authors can see this and fix this bug. however i noticed in your code that there are extra points where the thresholds meet - is there a way to get rid of this?

Comment: I don't think there are extra points, but the red points have the same (blue) fillcolor as the blue points.